# error in the transfert image

Tags: android, file, memory, bitmap, file-transfer

hello I have this error in the moment of i would like transfert a image in android. I don't understand why.

**EDIT: I have find the raison.The raison are they have insuffisant allowed Memory. How to change the allowed memory?**

```
   EDIT:FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

07-18 08:50:35.169: E/AndroidRuntime(16772):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
07-18 08:50:35.169: E/AndroidRuntime(16772):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
07-18 08:50:35.169: E/AndroidRuntime(16772):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:389)
07-18 08:50:35.169: E/AndroidRuntime(16772):    at P12.transferImage(P12.java:503)
07-18 08:50:35.169: E/AndroidRuntime(16772):    at P12.access$4(P12.java:487)
07-18 08:50:35.169: E/AndroidRuntime(16772):    at P12$6.onClick(P12.java:313)
07-18 08:50:35.169: E/AndroidRuntime(16772):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3644)
07-18 08:50:35.169: E/AndroidRuntime(16772):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14313)
07-18 08:50:35.169: E/AndroidRuntime(16772):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-18 08:50:35.169: E/AndroidRuntime(16772):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-18 08:50:35.169: E/AndroidRuntime(16772):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 08:50:35.169: E/AndroidRuntime(16772):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
07-18 08:50:35.169: E/AndroidRuntime(16772):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 08:50:35.169: E/AndroidRuntime(16772):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 08:50:35.169: E/AndroidRuntime(16772):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
07-18 08:50:35.169: E/AndroidRuntime(16772):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
07-18 08:50:35.169: E/AndroidRuntime(16772):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 08:55:44.474: I/Process(16772): Sending signal. PID: 16772 SIG: 9
07-18 08:55:44.764: D/dalvikvm(17129): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 65K, 4% free 12756K/13187K, paused 16ms
```

The problem's are in line

```
Bitmap imgTaken = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(from, options);
```

The url file are correct I have verified

This are the begin of my transfert function.

```
private void transferImage(String from,String imageName) throws IOException {
    Log.i("debug","from:"+from.toString());
    // we want remote host, user name and password
    if (from == null || from.length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.errorFTPparameters), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setResult(11);
        finish();
    }

    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];

        // byte array transfers
        Bitmap imgTaken = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(from, options);

        if (imgTaken == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.errorcreatingstream), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            setResult(11);
            finish();
        }

        // transforming image into byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imgTaken.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

        // base64 encoding of the bytes in a string
        String bos1 = Base64.encodeBytes(bitmapdata);
        //...
```

Comment: Please also provide the exception/error message with your stacktrace.

Comment: thank's. I forgot the first part of the error

Answer (score 0):

Well, your image is to big to fit in the memory, that Android has allocated for you.
If you don't need the full resolution picture, try [setting the image size](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/74NNLVN6AN0) upfront to something smaller using [`inSampleSize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize):

```
options.inSampleSize = 2 //gives you an image with half the height/width
```

If you need the full resolution picture, please clarify what exactly you want to achieve with your `transferImage` function, then maybe we can provide you with an alternative way.

Comment: i Have test but it's not the problem's. It's because the totality of the memory allowed it's insufficient. How to change the allowed memory?

Comment: Android decides how much memory you get, you can't influence it. Try some higher values for `inSampleSize` or use some approach to [automatically calculate it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/823966/1467115).